# Fail to read integers from C-Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, integer, arrays

I created a NSObject-Class called "leveldesign". There I created an integer C-Array. Now I'm trying to read the numbers in my "ViewController.m" class. But if I NSLog() the integers I get numbers like 1245 or 2104.... But in my C-Array are only 0,1 and 2.. 
Thanks for your help!

Code "leveldesign.h"

```
extern int level[1][5];

@interface leveldesign : NSObject

@end
```

Code "leveldesign.m"

```
#import "leveldesign.h"

int level[1][5] = {

    {0,1,2,0,2}

};

@implementation leveldesign

@end
```

Code "ViewController.m"

```
#import "leveldesign.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  NSLog(@"%i", level[1][1]);
  NSLog(@"%i", level[1][3]);

}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Array indices start at 0.

change this:

```
NSLog(@"%i", level[1][1]);
NSLog(@"%i", level[1][3]);
```

to this:

```
NSLog(@"%i", level[0][0]);
NSLog(@"%i", level[0][2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `NSLog(@"%d", level[1][3]);` with the '**d**' format specifier instead of '**i**'?